# CANON EOS 70D: In Manual mode, shutter speed is changing when i adjust the exposure level

Tags: canon

My canon eos 70d, in manual mode the shutter speed is changing when i adjust the exposure level.  How to fix this? please help.

Comment: How are you adjusting the exposure level?

Comment: I have a Canon 70D and you guys are not paying attention to the question. I have experienced several times on my 70D the shutter speed changing in manual mode after setting it. Several times I would check images after taking a couple of shots to find that in manual mode my shutter speed went from 1/100 to 1/30 causing my images to blur obviously. After reading manual, there is no mention of "exposure compensation" as you mention here. Automatic adjustments is not a blessing IMO in manual mode.

Comment: @Richard We were trying to make sense of the question given the small amount of information provided. OP says he/she adjusted the "exposure level." There is of course no single *exposure level* setting, though there *is* an *exposure compensation* setting (see page 167 in your manual, "Setting Exposure Compensation"). As explained in my answer, changing the shutter speed is one way to change the value shown in the meter, and it sounds like that's what the OP was actually doing. If we get more information, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 5):

> My canon eos 70d, in manual mode the shutter speed is changing when i adjust the exposure level. How to fix this?

**You're looking at it backward.** You're adjusting the shutter speed, and *because* you changed the shutter speed the exposure level indicated by the meter will change. In manual mode, the meter tells you what exposure to expect based on the shutter speed, aperture, ISO, and lighting. If you change any of those, the meter will change.

**Try this:** In manual mode, change the shutter speed a few times to confirm that the exposure changes. Next, without touching either of the control wheels, point the camera at something darker or lighter than what you were previously looking at. You'll see the exposure level change even though the settings are all the same.

Answer (score 1):

That is no bug – it is a feature :-). If you change your exposure, shutter speed (or aperture or ISO) have to change otherwise it would be complete useless, because the combination of shutter speed, aperture and ISO *is* your exposure.

**For your 70D** (I tested on my 70D)**:** in manual mode you can´t change the exposure compensation. When you change the shutter speed the exposure *indicator* is changing.

Comment: The exposure indicator may vary in style but the behaviour is the same on the 40D and even the 350D (I was using mine in manual mode a couple of days ago). You can see that you're changing the shutter speed and the exposure level isn't constant if you arrange non-constant lighting e.g. by waving your name on front of the source.